# Magento Config - Allow specific IP to Access a Route

Tags: apache, magento, vagrant, puppet, puphpet

I know that using apache directives, one can deny / allow access to certain files based on IP address:

```
Allow from address
```

However, in Magento, there's a particular module / route where I'd like only one IP to have access.  Is there a way to specify this int he configuration / xml for that module?

Otherwise, can I use the .htaccess method in some way?

Lastly, I'm using Puphpet / Vagrant environment for this project.  Is it possible to specify this in the Puphpet config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using the available bash script hooks.  I created a bash script that added this specific directive to the nginx.conf, and placed it in `puphpet/files/startup-always`.  So every time `vagrant up` or `vagrant provision` is run, this bash script is executed.